# How to bring the text exactly in the middle of any block elements using flex property?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a `div` with width 100px and height 100px, but I want the text to be aligned in the middle of the `div`.

I have used text align center for the horizontal alignment, for vertical alignment i tried using `vertical-align` property. It's not working, then I used `line-height` for making the content exactly in the middle of the document. The line height will vary for each and every element depending upon the content. Is there any appropriate solution for this issue?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
    .dragg-elem div {
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      border: 2px solid #ccc;
      display: inline-block;
      line-height: 90px;
      text-align:center;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="dragg-elem">
        <div id="one">1</div>
        <div id="two">2</div>
        <div id="three">3</div>
        <div id="four">4</div>
        <div id="five">5</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can rely on using flexbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use flex for this.

You can also view this in full page it will be centered both vertically and horizontally.

Try this

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
  .dragg-elem{
    display:flex; 
    align-items:center;
    height:100vh;
    justify-content: center;
  }
.dragg-elem div {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
border: 2px solid #ccc;
display: inline-block;
line-height: 90px;
text-align:center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="dragg-elem">
    <div id="one">1</div>
    <div id="two">2</div>
    <div id="three">3</div>
    <div id="four">4</div>
    <div id="five">5</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

with `display:inline-flex;` :

```
.dragg-elem div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}
```

Or with `line-height;` and `text-align:center;` . But `line-height` must be equal with box height.

```
.dragg-elem div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: This will be hard when checking responsive

Comment: why? use the first method?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
```